# парсер xml проблема с <> и &

Tags: php, xml

при разборе simplexml файла не обрабатываются строки, в которых есть данные заключенные в угловые кавычки (<>) или знак &.
Подскажите, плиз, как решить.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю эти символы должны экранироваться. Почитайте https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML абзац "Решение проблемы неоднозначности разметки"

Comment: проблема в том, что обрабатываются пришедшие извне файлы. Расставлять экраны перед обработкой файла задача нетривиальная, поскольку файлов обрабатывается более сотни за раз, но мне кажется немного неправильная. Например вьювер IE вполне справляется. Значит есть решение. Хотелось бы это решение узнать

Comment: руками если перебирать

Comment: А структура приходящих извне файлов заранее известна?

Comment: Ну если из вне значит пишите баг репорт и ждёте решения ничего от вас не зависит

Comment: пример файла то будет?

Comment: я-то предварительно могу прогнать скриптом с заменой, но просто надеялся на более изящное решение.

Comment: <prog times="10.15" type="Художественный фильм">
     <name lang="ru" mode="short">Х/ф "Клятва" <*>.</name>
    </prog> В этом блоке присутствует <*>